# Is it possible to regenerate firefox's profiles.ini from existing profiles?

Tags: firefox-profile

I recently accidentally filled my home partition in Ubuntu.  Before I realized what happened, I restarted Firefox because it was acting strangely (understandably).

Now, when I start firefox with the Profile Manager (using -p) it doesn't list any of my existing profiles.  I checked and all the profile folders are still there but my profiles.ini file is basically empty.  I presume it got blanked by accident while the partition was full.

I tried deleting the profiles.ini but it just gets regenerated empty.  Is it possible to regenerate my profiles.ini based on the existing profile folders or will I just have to rebuild it by hand (the mozilla docs show the format so it doesn't look too hard to do, I'm just looking for the lazy option).

Answer (score 4):

Some Bash-love; name it whatever you like.  I used thescript.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo '[General]'
echo 'StartWithLastProfile=1'
echo ''

n=0

for file in * ; do
  if [[ -d "$file" ]] ; then
    if [[ "$file" =~ .+\.(.+) ]] ; then
      echo "[Profile${n}]"
      echo "Name=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
      echo "IsRelative=1"
      echo "Path=${file}"
      if [[ "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" == default ]] ; then
        echo "Default=1"
      fi
      echo ""
      let n++
    fi
  fi
done
```

### Usage

First, place it in your mozilla profiles directory (e.g. ~/.mozilla/firefox for me).

```bash
chmod +x thescript.sh
./thescript.sh
./thescript.sh > profiles.ini
```

### Output

```bash
nex@Computer:~/.mozilla/firefox
$ ./thescript.sh 
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=03k202kd.default
Default=1

[Profile1]
Name=test
IsRelative=1
Path=a023lkdl.test


nex@Computer:~/.mozilla/firefox
$ ./thescript.sh > profiles.ini
```

Comment: Nice, I should have mentioned how to use mine as well.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find anything googling so I wrote a perl script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = glob($ARGV[0] || '~/.mozilla/firefox/');

chdir $dir or die "Unable to change to dir $dir: $!";
opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Unable to open dir $dir: $!";
my @dirs = grep { /^[^.]/ && -d $_ } readdir $dh;

# print some boilerplate
print <<'START';
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=0

START

# try to sort by oldest first (uses a schwartzian transform)
# the 'chrome' folder in each profile folder seems to be the oldest file per profile generally
@dirs = reverse
        map { $_->[0] }
        sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] || $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] }
        map { [ $_, -C "$_/chrome" ] }
        grep { -e "$_/chrome" } @dirs;

my $i = 0;
foreach my $profile_dir (@dirs) {
    # folder names are usually of the form zyxwabc.My Profile Name
    my ($name) = $profile_dir =~ /^[^.]+\.(.*)/;
    next if ! $name;

    print <<"PROFILE";
[Profile$i]
Name=$name
IsRelative=1
Path=$profile_dir

PROFILE

    $i++;
}
```